# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in telebot(python)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

всем привет! написал код для ilnile кнопок в telebot, код написал, всё ПО-МОЕМУ хорошо:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startJoin(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open('C://tgbot/user_ids.txt', "a")
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)
# keyboard
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    butt1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('/cmd', callback_data='cmd')

    markup.add(butt1)

# Welcome
    send_welcome = f'<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!</b>\n\n' + 'Бот в стадии разработки.' + "\n\nДля помощи, используйте команду /cmd\n\nЕсли у тебя есть идея для бота, или же придумал новую команду - пиши в /report [text] :)\n"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_welcome, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'cmd':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, send_cmd, parse_mode='html')
bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

но при запуске выдает ошибку в консоли:

```
C:\Users\timur>python c://tgbot/bot.py
  File "c://tgbot/bot.py", line 121

                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: `try:` вижу, а где `except:`??

Comment: точно! не заметил даже...Спасибо огромное!!!